# Low network throughput between EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

I have two t2.medium Windows Server 2003 EC2 instances setup in the same VPC subnet in us-east-1. The network throughput between them is very low. Running iperf between them consistently shows transfer rates around 330 Kbits/sec.

By comparison, this VPC is configured with a VPN connection to my local office, and if I run iperf between one of the EC2 instances and a machine in my office, I consistently see about 3 Mbits/sec.

ping between instances shows 1ms response times

tracert between instances shows 1 hop @1ms

I have tried stopping and restarting the instances

I'm not aware of any configuration options that would influence this.

Any ideas what might be inhibiting the network connection between the instances?

**UPDATE 1**

[WinSCP confirms slow connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFCsB.jpg) (342 Kbits/sec)

[iperf between instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/190D4.jpg) (364 Kbits/sec average)

My reputation allows me to post only two links, so see the urls below for the other screenshots (added by editor)

iperf local to aws instance 1 (6.91 Mbit/sec average): `https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df0CP.jpg`

[image: iperf local to aws instance 1]

iperf local to aws instance 2 (7.43 Mbit/sec average): `https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAWOf.jpg`

[image: iperf local to aws instance 2]

There are no firewalls configured on either instance

CPU usage does not increase during the WinSCP transfer

Flow logs are off on the VPC

**UPDATE 2**

Here are the route tables. Anything look unusual here?

server 1 route table: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uODP.jpg`

server 2 route table: `https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOmuo.jpg`

Comment: Can you try another test between the machines? sftp/scp etc? It will validate the problem. Ideally show screenshots. What happens if you run iperf between your office PC and the other machine? Is there any kind of firewall running on the instance? Does CPU usage go up on either? Do you have flow logs turned on in your VPC (shouldn't matter)?

Comment: I'll look into the others tests. Not clear on what you mean by "between your office pc and the other machine". Can you say it another way?

Comment: You have two EC2 servers. You've said the performance between your office PC and one of the EC2 servers is 3Mbps. I suggested doing a test from your office PC to the other EC2 server. If it's significantly slower than the first EC2 server it helps narrow down the problem. It's probably not that, but it's good to rule it out.

Comment: Ah, I see thanks. I have done that and saw the same result.

Comment: Please look into the things I suggested and edit your questions with additional information / answers. Demonstrate the problem, in multiple ways if you can. I can't think of a good reason this would happen, I get much higher speeds between my instances, tens of MB/sec from memory.

Comment: Most definitely, @Tim.  My guess: one or both instances have a spurious, equal cost route table entry to the other instance -- in the instance's route table, not the VPC route table -- or maybe multiple ENIs attached, with a misconfiguration -- causing ~50% packet loss on local traffic, and bringing throughput to a crawl.  It sounds like it's wireshark time.

Comment: @Tim: I've updated the question with the info you requested

Comment: This is pretty bizarre. I have no idea sorry. I'd probably spin up two more basic Amazon Linux instances in the VPC and see if they have the same problem, between the new instances and between one new and one old. It would also prove it was an instance level problem not a VPC problem. If it helps you might be best off setting up your service(s) on new instances.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I've added screenshots of the server route tables. Anything look out of place?

Comment: It may also be worth noting that these are brand new instances that aren't in production yet. As far as I know, this issue has existed from the beginning

Comment: Are they based linux images, some customised AMI, etc? Did you try with stock Amazon Linux instances?

Comment: they are stock windows server 2003 AMIs

Comment: Route tables seem normal.  Possibly interesting reading here, though, about the Citrix PV Ethernet Adapter: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Upgrading_PV_drivers.html

Comment: I setup two instances running Win Server 2016 on the same instance size. Throughput between them reports ~1 Gbps. Running 2016 iperf client and 2003 server, throughput is still in that range. With 2003 client, and 2016 server, throughput drops to about 1 Mbps. The default TCP window size on 2016 is 64KB and on 2003 it is 8KB. If I tell 2003 client to use 64K window with 2016 server, the throughput increases to ~600 Mbps. If I use 64K window between the two 2003 servers, throughput goes up to ~600 Mbps. 8KB window on 2016 client to 2003 server gets 300Kbps

Comment: Now I'm wondering if there is actually a throughput problem, or if its just iperf and WinSCP

Comment: Timing the transfer of large files via windows explorer between the 2003 instances shows rates consistently between 100 and 200 Mbps (although, for some reason, initiating a transfer from one of the two in a particular direction is consistently between 400 and 500 Mbps)